# Create a bitonal image for OCR using Image Magick

Tags: image, imagemagick, ocr

```
nice /usr/local/bin/convert \
  -colors 2 \
  -colorspace gray \
  -compress group4 \
   /var/www/html/uploads/pokemon.jpg \
   /var/www/html/uploads/pokemontest.jpg
```

This command worked with a really OLD version of Image Magick.

With the newest version this method produces a completely black image.

```
nice /usr/local/bin/convert \
  -colorspace gray \
  -compress group4 \
   /var/www/html/uploads/pokemon.jpg \
   /var/www/html/uploads/pokemontest.jpg

nice /usr/local/bin/convert \
   -colors 2 \
    /var/www/html/uploads/pokemontest.jpg \
    /var/www/html/uploads/pokemontestfinal.jpg
```

This results in a bitonal gray and black image, but it's really rough. NOT clean at all.

Comment: I tested the first command on Ubuntu imagemagic version `6.6.2-6 2010-12-02 Q16` and it work fine. Maybe something is wrong with the image.

Comment: I don't know how to express this in ImageMagick terms, but I suppose better results could be attained by using adaptive thresholding, instead of global thresholding. Maybe the default implementation has changed?

Comment: Can you post (a link to) a sample input file of yours?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a simple

```
convert  input.jpg  -threshold 50%  output.jpg
```

(and play a bit with variations of the `50%` setting) and see if this gets you any further.

Also, you may want to have a look at these answers:

- [Image Preprocessing steps to improve the recognition rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006866/image-preprocessing-steps-to-improve-the-recognition-rate/)